# RectTransform tracking gameObject smoothly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like a RectTransform (panel) in Unity 4.6 to follow a worldObject. I got this working, but the movement is not as smooth as I'd like. It seems a bit jagged and it lags behind when I start moving the camera.

```
    Vector2 followObjectScreenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (planet.transform.position);
    rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2 (followObjectScreenPos.x - Screen.width / 2, followObjectScreenPos.y - Screen.height / 2);
```

Tips and tricks are greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bunch of options:

1) You can add a gui canvas to the worldObject and render your panel with this canvas (just add it as a child), but that may not be exactly what you need.

2) To eliminate jagged movement you should tween in one way or another. DOTween is my personal preference, where something along the following lines would give you the required result:

```
Tweener tweener = transfrom.DOMove (Target.position, 1).SetSpeedBased();
tweener.OnUpdate (() => tweener.ChangeEndValue (Target.position, true));
```

3) if you don't want to include dependencies in your code, you can perform linear interpolation between current and desired position (or in your case - anchoredPosition) in Update function.

I'd suggest using a tweener so as not to clutter your update function and generally tweeners have loads of potential uses in all kinds of games.

Below is code sample for linear interpolation in case you don't want to use tweener library:

```
float smoothFactor = 1.0f; //used to sharpen or dull the effect of lerp
var newPosition = new Vector3(x,y,z);
var t = gameObject.transform;
t.position = Vector3.Lerp (t.position,
                           newPosition,
                           Time.deltaTime * smoothFactor);
```

Place it in Update function and it will make the gameObject follow specific `newPosition`.